# Is this sect appropriate for an answer?

Tags: discussion

A while ago, I asked the question [Do any denominations teach that Adam and Eve had children in the Garden of Eden?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/77347/do-any-denominations-teach-that-adam-and-eve-had-children-in-the-garden-of-eden), of the back of another question. Perhaps unsurprisingly, it hasn't gained any answer, so I did some research to see if I could answer it myself.

I came across a reference that does explicitly state that Adam and Eve had children in the Garden of Eden. The Urantian Book appears to be a modern 're-write' of the story of the Bible, which according to its [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Urantia_Book) "claim to be a clarification and expansion of Christian belief".

Personally this is something I would very strongly oppose - the Bible is the only way we can know God. However, reference to it would answer the question. If we accept traditions that use other source (e.g. the Book of Mormon), would it be appriopriate to write an answer referencing this Urantia Book?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Many people think that The Urantia Book is in itself a "religion, " but it's not.
>   …
>   It seems vital to me to start to re-define what "religion" really means. The Urantia Book, while not in itself a religion, does inspire in the believer a new understanding of what religion really is, and the necessity for it in our lives.
>   …
>   You asked if I consider myself a Christian...I do not. Jesus himself was not a "Christian"
>   — [Are Urantia Book believers Christian?](https://truthbook.com/urantia/faq/are-urantia-book-believers-christian)

That document links to [Religion in The Urantia Book](https://truthbook.com/urantia/topical-studies/religion).

It appears that Urantia is more of a meta-religion, discussing what religion is, and how one should view it and practice it rather than what one should actually believe.  It is a philosophy, not a religion.

Given that it is not Christian, and not even a religion, it would be appropriate on this site only in the same way quotations from other philosophical works would be.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, that's certainly an edge case. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Urantia_Book#Adherents) does say there are no formal churches or clergy, but also notes that there are dozens of associations with thousands of members.

I think I'd say that it would be okay to include for that particular question, but I'm not sure I'd want them turning up a lot. But if anyone can find an official source from the Urantia Foundation or International Urantia Association showing the self-identify as "Christian" then I think we'd have to include them as we do all other self-identifiers.

Comment: Looking further, it seems they [wouldn't identify as Christian](https://truthbook.com/urantia/faq/are-urantia-book-believers-christian), so wouldn't generally be appropriate for this site?

Comment: Believe that Curiousdanii has made the correct call. **Jesusonian** is simply a bumfuzzling way of saying **Christian**.

Comment: @Ken On the other hand, according to the quote in Ray's answer, they overtly reject the label "Christian". No need for us to out of our way to include the nonsense from this new age sect if they don't even want to be called Christians!

Comment: Truly  said, it may be harder to navigate the New Age terminology and still remain balanced intellectually!!!

Comment: @curiousdannii Yes, I think I agree, and I've accepted Ray's answer. While it's interesting that there is a group who believe this, they don't make for an answer. I might leave a comment on my question noting them as an 'interesting fact'